# битые пакеты при установке OBS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update, terminal

Пытаюсь поставить OBS. На мою команду в терминале `sudo apt-get install obs-studio` он мне отвечает следующее:

```js
Сущ:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Сущ:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Сущ:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Сущ:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Сущ:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Сущ:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                                      
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 obs-studio : Зависит: libluajit-5.1-2 но он не может быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

OBS ранее стоял, потом я его удалил, сейчас снова нужен. Подскажите как можно разрешить зависимости?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @donRumata неа, ничего не обновляет не устанавливает, проблема остается((

Comment: А если грохнуть репу с obs и сделать `apt update`?

Comment: Вот только что воткнул в свой `xenial`. И всё поехало с первого раза. Покажи мне выхлоп `aptitude show libluajit-5.1-2`

Comment: @donRumata `aptitude show libluajit-5.1-2
Нет в наличии или подходящей версии для libluajit-5.1-2
Пакет: libluajit-5.1-2
Состояние: не реальный пакет`

Comment: `sudo apt update`